# Sequencal Workflow Designer

Tags: workflow, workflow-foundation

I am looking for some kind of a workflow editor for WF, has anyone seen anything like this?

I would like to be able to edit XML files, but then have those XML files be opened by my app.

Maybe a different approach is ok too!

Bill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to [rehost the WF4 designer](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mcsuksoldev/archive/2012/03/26/workflow-foundation-wf4-rehosting-the-workflow-designer.aspx) in your app, similar to the one that is available in Visual Studio. Its also possible to host it on Internet Explorer as an [XBAP application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970060%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

As for manipulating the XAML XML file(s) containing your workflow structure, the easiest way would be to create your activities via code and serialize them down (and up) using the `ActivityXamlServices` type. [See here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff458319%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more info on this.

Comment: AMAZING!  Thanks in advanced!  I will let you know how it works!

Comment: Nice, thanks for the find of that control. Going to mess with the toolkit's other controls very soon.

Comment: Ok so how do you use this in a web page like you were saying?  Do you have a link that would show how?

Comment: The following is a good starting point to creating an XBAP version of your app: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970060(v=vs.110).aspx